# primitive polynomial on $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For some reason I need some primitive polynomial $f$ on $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ where $\deg f \in [1,10^4]$. (Especially for $\deg f = 10\pm \epsilon, 10^2\pm \epsilon, 10^3\pm \epsilon, 10^4 \pm \epsilon$.)
Could someone give information about this? For example, a table or some references are helpful. Thx.

Edit: If $2^{\deg f} - 1 \in \mathbb{P}$ we have that an irreducible polynomial $f$ is primitive immediately. However assuredly primitive polynomial exists for all $\deg f \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $.

Comment: Is "primitive polynomial" the same as an irreducible polynomial?

Comment: To Greg, if $2^{\deg f}-1 \in \mathbb{P}$, then you are right. Or see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)

Comment: But if $\deg f$ is a power of $10$ then $2^{\deg f} - 1$ is not prime.  The factorization is known for $10$, $10^2$, and $10^3$ (see the table at  http://members.iinet.net.au/~tmorrow/mathematics/cunningham/c02minus.html), but I don't know whether $10^4$ is at all feasible, and that's the main hurdle to finding a provably primitive polynomial of degree $10^4$.

Comment: Ok, I see. So $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is an example of an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb F_2$ that is not primitive.